# Enable and Disable in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I try to make disable second field until I do not enter 'Lokesh' in first field for that I have tried below code I am in learning stage of angularjs so please correct me where I am doing mistake.

eg.code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
       <html>
          <script src= "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>
        <body>

            <p>Enter 'Lokesh' to display last name</p>

                <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">



                    <input data-ng-model="firstName"  

                   type="text"  

                   ng-disabled="{if(firstName="lokesh")}"

                   Last Name: <input type="text" ng-model="lastName"><br>
                   />


                  <script>
                    var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
                    app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {

                    $scope.lastName= "Kumar Gaurav";
                    });

            </script>                               
    </body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with the attribute `ng-disabled="{if(firstName=" lokesh ")}"`

There is no need of using `if`, you can directly compare the strings.

Update the code as

```
ng-disabled="firstName=='lokesh'"
```

**Demo**

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.0/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app>
  <input data-ng-model="firstName" class="span12 editEmail" type="text" placeholder="Type lokesh here" />Last Name:
  <input type="text" ng-model="lastName" ng-disabled="firstName!=='lokesh'" />
  <br>{{firstName}}

</div>
```

Comment: @LokeshKumarGaurav Please check the demo included.

Comment: @LokeshKumarGaurav There are errors in HTML element tags, if you properly close them, it should work

Comment: Sorry Tushar bro actually by mistake I wrote class="span12 editEmail".  I want to show both field but once I put 'Lokesh' for field first then second field should be highlighted.

Comment: @LokeshKumarGaurav You mean second field should be disabled, right?

Comment: @LokeshKumarGaurav I've updated demo, please check again

Comment: Sorry for asking again Tushar. If I want to first field enable and second field disable and after entering lokesh in first field. Second field should be in enable otherwise disable only. please suggest me by code